# Using JWebUnit for TDD approach for Spring webflow application

Tags: tdd, spring-webflow-2, jwebunit

My project involves Spring Webflow.
I would like to use TDD approach for developing web pages. (ie) JSP etc..
If there is change in jsp I want to test I dont want to restart the whole server

I have heard in one of the talks from Rod Johnson that JWebUnit is useful for unit testing webpages in this case..

I could not find any articles or books that describe this approach..

Hence it will be very useful for me If I am provided pointers in that direction..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article that might help you.  I hope it does

http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/12/13/and-now-by-popular-demand-jwebunit/